# custom plugin no showing in admin menu

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a custom plugin that is showing and activated with no errors or warnings in wordpress->plugins but is not showing in the wordpress admin menu can anyone see why not please?

```
<?php
/**
 * Owed Trips
 *
 * @package       Owed Trips
 * @author        Mike Jones
 * @license       gplv2
 * @version       1.0.0
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:   Owed Trips
 * Plugin URI:    www.xxxxxx.co.uk
 * Description:   Owed Trips
 * Version:       1.0.0

 * Author:        Mike Jones
 * Author URI:    www.xxxxxx.co.uk
 * Text Domain:   owed-trips
 * Domain Path:   /languages
 * License:       GPLv2
 * License URI:   https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with Owed Trips. If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html/>.
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

/**
 * HELPER COMMENT START
 *
 * This file contains the main information about the plugin.
 * It is used to register all components necessary to run the plugin.
 *
 * The comment above contains all information about the plugin
 * that are used by WordPress to differenciate the plugin and register it properly.
 * It also contains further PHPDocs parameter for a better documentation
 *
 * The function OWED_TRIPS() is the main function that you will be able to
 * use throughout your plugin to extend the logic. Further information
 * about that is available within the sub classes.
 *
 * HELPER COMMENT END
 */

// Plugin name
define( 'OWED_TRIPS_NAME',                       'Owed Trips' );

// Plugin version
define( 'OWED TRIPS_VERSION',            '1.0.0' );

// Plugin Root File
define( 'OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_FILE',        __FILE__ );

// Plugin base
define( 'OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_BASE',        plugin_basename( OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_FILE ) );

// Plugin Folder Path
define( 'OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_FILE ) );

// Plugin Folder URL
define( 'OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_FILE ) );

/**
 * Load the main class for the core functionality
 */
require_once OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_DIR . 'core/class-owed-trips.php';

/**
 * The main function to load the only instance
 * of our master class.
 *
 * @author  Mike Jones
 * @since   1.0.0
 * @return  object|Owed Trips
 */

function Owed_Trips() {
        return Owed_Trips::instance();
}

OWED_TRIPS();

function owed_trips_register_post_types() {

        // Set UI labels for the recipes post type.
        $labels = array(
                'name' => _x( 'Owed Trips', 'Post Type General Name', 'owed_trips' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Owed_Trips', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'owed_trips' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Owed Trips', 'owed_trips' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Owed Trips', 'owed_trips' ),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Owed Trips', 'owed_trips' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Owed Trips', 'owed_trips' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Owed Trip', 'owed_trips' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'owed_trips' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Owed Trip', 'owed_trips' ),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Owed Trip', 'owed_trips' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Owed Trips', 'owed_trips' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'Not Found', 'owed_trips' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'owed_trips' ),
        );

        // Set other arguments for the recipes post type.
        $args = array(
                'label' => __( 'Owed Trip', 'owed_trip' ),
                'description' => __( 'Owed Trips', 'owed_trips' ),
                'labels' => $labels,
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'excerpt',
                        'author',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'comments',
                        'revisions',
                        'custom-fields',
                ),
                'taxonomies' => array(),
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'can_export' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'show_in_rest' => true,
        );

        // Registers the recipes post type.
        register_post_type( 'recipes', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'owed_trips_register_post_types' );
```

I thought the last line add_action('init', 'owed_trips_register_post_types' ); was what added the function name to the admin menu in position 5

Comment: I think due to this OWED_TRIPS() function. I think it should be Owed_Trips(). Can you please check?

Comment: changed: /**OWED_TRIPS();*/
owed_trips();   no change, thanks though

Comment: Owed_Trips() not owed_trips()

Comment: Sorry, changed to Owed_Trips(); no change.  I did deactivate and reactivate the plugin as well

Comment: Well, then you need to check the core/class file. Because if I comment the file path and Owed_tips() function, it works fine. Admin menu is showing.

Comment: Strange, I just did the same. commented out the file path require_once OWED_TRIPS_PLUGIN_DIR . 'core/class-owed-trips.php'; and Owed_Trips();  didn't see Owed Trips appear in the admin menu

Comment: That's strange. Turn on debug mode from config file and check if there is any error from your plugin.

Comment: debug on, (wp_debug=true) no errors, I even created a new plugin from one I did a few months ago and substituted where necessary (routes-interface) and the plugin activates with no errors but still no sign of it in the admin menu,